# How to include nested datatable with custom columns

Tags: apex, aura, lightning-datatable, datatable

Currently, I'm displaying the aggregate list of opportunities in a data table along with a custom button named "View Details" as a column. When someone clicks this button I want to display opportunities calculated in the aggregate list But I'm not sure how to display the data table within a data table. I have looked at the treegrid option but I'm unable to display custom columns within a nested table.

[image]

Is it possible to display in this way.
[image]

Comment: Perhaps a more appropriate solution would be a modal with a lightning-record-form instead.

Comment: @Pavantej Did you find the solution for above requirement?